# Mercurial Repository - Automatic daily hg add/hg commit command on server

Tags: mercurial, hook, commit, mercurial-hook

I have a web server which is using mercurial as the repository.  Every day, we have files being written by applications to our server and I want these to be reflected in the repository.  Is there a way to add an automated 'hg add' and 'hg commit' command that runs every day so these files are kept track of and can be "pulled" by our developers on their machines?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scheduling tasks is not a job for mercurial.  see crontab or Scheduled Tasks depending on your OS.

Comment: Ah yes, I just created a batch file in windows that will go to the directory and run the hg add and hg commit commands. Not sure why I was looking for mercurial to do the job.  Thanks for your help!